# How to activate email notification on visa expiry date on odoo

Tags: odoo-11

I'm using the version 11 and i want to know how can i activate the email reminder on visa expiry date. I searched on the net but i found a solution only for an older version  and it wasn't clear. Any idea for help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this module to inspire you, you can apply the same principal,

[Quotation Expiry Reminder odoo 11](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/quotation_expiry_reminder/)

this module send mails to the sales person based on the reminder settings.

I hope my answer will be helpful